# MySQL performs a slow query with a boolean condition

Tags: mysql, sql

Example of the table:

```
       id       |      source     | removed
17D30437329A9B9 |                 |   0
M851X0LG81045F  | 17D30437329A9B9 |   0
QQG1RU1M8E5JHO  |                 |   0
QDVHFNFKF0Z80W  | 17D30437329A9B9 |   0
8BEFSFGUPBXJHV  |                 |   0
```

When I query:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    `uploads`
WHERE   (id = '17D30437329A9B9 ' OR `source` = '17D30437329A9B9 ')
AND     removed = 0
```

The query takes ~25 seconds (I have ~17 million rows).

But when I run this:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    `uploads`
WHERE   (id = '17D30437329A9B9 ' OR `source` = '17D30437329A9B9 ')
```

Or this:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    `uploads`
WHERE   (`id` = '17D30437329A9B9 ')
AND     removed = 0
```

Or that:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    `uploads`
WHERE   (`source` = '17D30437329A9B9 ')
AND     removed = 0
```

The queries runs fast.

Why is the 1st query runs really slow, and how can I fix it?

EDIT:
The result from `EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM uploads WHERE (id = '17D30437329A9B9 ' OR source = '17D30437329A9B9 ') AND removed = 0;`:

```
+----+-------------+---------+------+-------------------------------------------------------+---------+---------+-------+---------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table   | type | possible_keys                                         | key     | key_len | ref   | rows    | Extra       |
+----+-------------+---------+------+-------------------------------------------------------+---------+---------+-------+---------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | uploads | ref  | PRIMARY,removed,source,idx_member_selectFiles,id,id_2 | removed | 1       | const | 8829521 | Using where |
+----+-------------+---------+------+-------------------------------------------------------+---------+---------+-------+---------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

it seem that there is no composite index.

run this and try again

**Create composite INDEX**

```
ALTER TABLE `uploads`
ADD KEY (`id`,`source`,`removed`);
```

please let me know if it works.

Comment: No, it still takes about 25 seconds. Also, before I already had a similar index but also with another column named "server" -  (`id`,`source`,`server`,`removed`). Maybe it's disturbing it somehow?

Comment: please post the output from : EXPLAIN SELECT  *
FROM    `uploads`
WHERE   (id = '17D30437329A9B9 ' OR `source` = '17D30437329A9B9 ')
AND     removed = 0;

Comment: they not use the best index. lets see why. please add also the output from: SHOW CREATE TABLE uploads;  and SELECT * FROM uploads PROCEDURE ANALYSE(); - thanks

Comment: do I need to do that on production with the 17 million rows, or can I do that on localhost with several rows?

Comment: they look only at a few k rows, but first you can post it from localhost

Answer (score 0):

The MySQL execution plans for queries with `OR` conditions are sometimes not optimal.

I suggest you re-write the query to combine results from two separate queries.

```
SELECT u1.*
  FROM `uploads` u1
 WHERE u1.id      = '17D30437329A9B9 '
   AND u1.removed = 0

 UNION ALL

SELECT u2.*
  FROM `uploads` u2
 WHERE u2.source  = '17D30437329A9B9 '
   AND u2.removed = 0
   AND NOT (u2.id <=> '17D30437329A9B9 ')
```

Each SELECT can make effective use of the most appropriate index.

The first SELECT can use an index with leading column of `id`.  The second SELECT can use an index with leading column of `source`.

---

FOLLOWUP

Q: And if i'm using IN? like WHERE (id IN ('a','b') OR source IN ('a','b')) AND removed = 0

A: I'd use the same approach.

```
SELECT u1.*
  FROM `uploads` u1
 WHERE u1.id     IN ('17D30437329A9B9 ', ... )
   AND u1.removed = 0

 UNION ALL

SELECT u2.*
  FROM `uploads` u2
 WHERE u2.source IN ('17D30437329A9B9 ', ... )
   AND u2.removed = 0
   AND ( u2.id IS NULL OR u2.id NOT IN ('17D30437329A9B9 ', ... ) )
```

The last condition on the second SELECT is intended to prevent the query from  returning a row that was already returned by the first SELECT.

With the NOT IN, just be **sure** that *none* of the values in the list are NULL. (If the NOT IN list includes a NULL value, then no rows will satisfy the condition.)

If the `id` column in `uploads` is guaranteed to be NOT NULL, the check for NULL can be eliminated. (We don't see any table definition, so we can't tell whether `id` is defined as NOT NULL, so write the query to work in the more general case, rather than based on a possibly wrong assumption.)

Comment: And if i'm using `IN`? like `WHERE (id IN ('a','b') OR source IN ('a','b')) AND removed = 0`

Comment: I recommend the same approach...  one SELECT to do the "`id IN ()`" and another SELECT to do the "`source IN ()`". We want the first one to be able to use an index with leading column of `id`, and the second to use an index with leading column `source`.

Answer (score 0):

B-Tree indexes are bad for columns with low cardinality. And in your case MySQL chooses the index for column `removed` what is VERY bad, because there only exist two distinct values.

I suspect to never see a benefit of the index on `removed`. Delete the index on `removed`.

A Bitmap-Index instead of a B-Tree Index would be good. As far as I know MySQL does not support Bitmap-Indexes.

Furthermore an index on `(id, source)` would help in this case.